# Reverse economization of Chebyshev series

Tags: approximation, regularization, chebyshev-polynomials

Suppose I have some function which is represented as converging series of Chebyshev polynomials of first kind in $[-1;1]$:
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n T_{2n}(x)
$$

I need to transform this series into power series,
$$
f(x)= \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty b_m x^{2m}.
$$

I have to separate terms with $x^2$ from other values in my analytical assumptions.
Is it possible?

I tried to do this by substitution of explicit form of $T_{2n}(x)$ into above series
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n n\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k(2n-k-1)!}{k!(2n-2k)!}(2x)^{2(n-k)}
$$

When I "collect" all of the coefficients for $x^2$:
$$
b_m = \frac{2^{2m}}{(2m)!}\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty a_n \frac{(-1)^{n}n(n+m-1)!}{(n-m)!}
$$
but this series diverge rapidly for all of my $a_n$.

I tried to do a zeta function regularization but I'm not good in this field and I don't know if regularization is formally correct or not; is it correct to chose the first Bernoulli number $B_1=-1/2$ to get $\zeta(0)=\sum n^0 = 1+1+...=-B_1=1/2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically,
in a Chebychev series,
the coefficients converge
pretty rapidly,
so you only consider
a finite number of them.

So you start with

$f(x)
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n T_{2n}(x)
$

and your result becomes

$b_m 
= \frac{2^{2m}}{(2m)!}\sum\limits_{n=m}^N a_n \frac{(-1)^{n}n(n+m-1)!}{(n-m)!}
$.

Note that
$b_m = 0$
for
$m > N$.

Also note that,
if we write
$b_{m, N} 
= \frac{2^{2m}}{(2m)!}\sum\limits_{n=m}^N a_n \frac{(-1)^{n}n(n+m-1)!}{(n-m)!}
$,
then
$b_{m, N}-b_{m, N-1} 
= \frac{2^{2m}}{(2m)!} a_{N} \frac{(-1)^{N}n(N+m-1)!}{(N-m)!}
= a_{N} (-1)^{N}2^{2m}n\frac{(N+m-1)!}{(2m)!(N-m)!}
= a_{N} (-1)^{N}2^{2m}N\binom{N+m}{2m}/(N+m)
$,
so this gives an idea
of how quickly
the $a_n$ have to convergs
to restore
the original polynomial.

It also shows why
the Chebychev economization
is a good thing.

Comment: So the main idea is to limit the number of coefficients? This is a first time I work with Chebyshev polynomials and I was surprised that then I limited the number of coefficients and calculated them I saw that all of them diverge rapidly but the whole approximation converges to my f(x) in $[-1,1$

Comment: Yes. In a typical Chebychev series, the error is about the first omitted term. Therefore, the series was probably chosen to be just accurate enough.

Comment: Thank you, It should be a good answer